# segmenting a series in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a large dataset with a few interesting pieces separated by long gaps.

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_file)
df.shape => (27968, 4)
df['Amperes'].plot()
```

[image]

The raw data is rather large; I 'd like to extract just the interesting (nearly non-zero) bits into a series of segments.  Finding the interesting bits is straightforward:

```
interesting_bits = df[:][df['Amperes'] > 0.1]
interesting_bits.shape => (3017, 4)
```

What is a sensible (or idiomatic) way to slice `interesting_bits` into a series (or list) of separate segments so I can examine each segment individually?

Comment: You question is a bit too broad. A sample data and expected output would help narrow down the question.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the suggestion.  Reworked the OP to be much more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can groupby the cumsum of the negate condition:

```
blocks = (df['Amperes'] <= 0.1).cumsum()

for block, data in df.query('Amperes > 0.1').groupby(blocks):
    print(data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully get it: the `blocks` cumsum will be stationary wherever Amperes > 0.1, which is fine: groupby() will create a block for entries > 0.1.  But for every entry in block < 0.1 will get a new cumsum, which turns into a new group, so I get zillions of single-element groups.

Comment: @fearless_fool you got it right. But you missed the .query part in the code.

Comment: Should the query be 'Amperes < 0.1' or 'Amperes > 0.1'?

Comment: You got it right again. Should be >. Thanks.